# Backtrace Queries Extremely Slow

Tags: c++, linux, g++, profiling, glibc

(Note: the following mentions [execinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execinfo_002eh.html) / 
[`backtrace`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html), but this is only an example. The behavior in the question appeared with various libraries.)

---

Consider a utility library that tracks the resource allocations of some application linked with it. As functions allocate and deallocate resources, they call a tracking function that records the details of the operation, as well as some information which can be used to reconstruct the call path. Occasionally, the library is queried for a breakdown of operations by call paths.

In the settings of this question, tracking is required to be low overhead, but querying not necessarily. Consequently, for tracking I stored the minimal information identifying the call path, e.g., by calling [execinfo](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execinfo_002eh.html)/ 
[`backtrace`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html). Translating the symbols, unmangling, and so forth, are deferred to queries, and are not part of this question.

To my surprise, simply calling `backtrace` slowed down execution by ~4000%(!) relative to the [`malloc`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) call. Since `backtrace` takes the requested (maximal) stack depth as an argument, and it can be called by call paths with different stack depths, I tried to see how these parameters affect its performance. As far as I can see, simply calling this function in any way has a huge penalty.

For the measurements I wrote the following simple code (see also the [full version](http://ideone.com/tT3LQa)):

```
const size_t max_backtrace_size = 100;
void *backtrace_buf[max_backtrace_size];   
static void track()
{
    if(backtrace_size > 0)
        ::backtrace(backtrace_buf, backtrace_size);
}

static void op(size_t i)
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        track();
        return;
    }
    op(i - 1);
}
```

The first of these two functions, `track`, simulates the actual tracking (note that `backtrace_size == 0` completely disables the call to `backtrace`); the second one, `op` is a recursion that terminates by calling `track`. Using these two functions, I varied the parameters and measured the results (see also [the IPython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/anonymous/6a91106b4c3a25b6ee7a)).

The following figure shows the tracking time, as a function of different stack sizes, for each of calling `backtrace` with `backtrace_size == 1` or not calling it (which has such low time that it lies on the X axis, and can hardly be seen in the figure). `backtrace` has a huge overhead even if called with small parameters.

[image: time as function of stack depth]

The following figure further shows the overhead, now as a function of both the backtrace size and stack depth. Again, there is a huge jump simply calling this function.

[image: time as a function of stack depth and backtrace size]

1. Is there any technical way to reduce the overhead of finding the backtrace? (perhaps a different library, or different build settings.)
2. In the absence of 1., is there a completely different viable alternative to the problem at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To my surprise, simply calling backtrace slowed down execution by ~4000%(!).

This statement, in itself, is meaningless. Even if `backtrace()` boiled down to a *single* instruction, it would still constitute `+INF` overhead if your other code contains no instructions at all.

A 40x overhead likely means that the resource you are trying to account for is exceedingly cheap to obtain. If so, perhaps not *every* instance of that resource must be accounted for? Could you for example record stack trace only for every `N`th resource allocation?

> Is there any technical way to reduce the overhead of finding the backtrace? (perhaps a different library, or different build settings.)

There are a few possibilities to consider.

Assuming you are asking about Linux/x86_64, one reason that `backtrace` is slow is that in the absence of frame pointers it has to find and interpret unwind information. Another reason: it is mostly used for handling exceptions, and was never optimized for speed.

If you have full control of the application that will use your library, building *everything* with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` would allow you to use much faster frame-based unwinder.

If you can't do that, [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) `backtrace` could be significantly faster than GLIBC one (though it still can't beat frame-based unwinder).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Much of what you wrote in the beginning re. the relative overhead is correct, but unfortunately stems from my inadvertent omission of relative overhead to *a ``malloc`` call* (I'll correct this in the question - thanks). About the sampling - that is what I ended up doing. Your point about the stack frame pointer is especially illuminating for it, and I'll read up on this further.

Answer (score 1):

All you are saying is that `backtrace` takes more time than `malloc`.
If you need what it tells you, there is a price to pay.

Was it ever intended to be super efficient, so it could be called with high frequency?

I'm sure its purpose is to diagnose problems like memory issues, for which you are calling it a lot, or performance issues, for which you don't need to call it a lot.

When you find the issues, you can fix them,
and when you no longer need `backtrace` you can stop calling it, and be happy that it helped you find them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This library checks for problems in servers deployed in the wild, and these servers must meanwhile service requests. Unfortunately, it is usually used for scenarios which also cannot be easily duplicated back in the lab. So it's a bit complicated to enable-fix-disable, without addressing the efficiency of the "fix" stage.

Comment: @AmiTavory: But still, whether or not it's efficient depends completely on the percent of time it costs, which depends on how many times per second it needs to be called. There are *so* many questions on SO where people say "How can I speed up library routine Foo?", without questioning if they really, actually, need to call it as often as they are.

Comment: Thanks again. You're of course right that it's really a question of the (# / time) fraction of the calls. In this case, the trackings were associated with ``malloc``s caused by operations initiated by the server's clients, and the rate of the clients` requests are beyond our control. We've been handling this by sampling randomly only some of the ops (which is basically an implementation of your idea here). Still, the more efficient the tracking, the higher the sampling rate (and less noise). Hence the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using libunwind, make sure to build your code with UNW_LOCAL_ONLY defined:

```
#define UNW_LOCAL_ONLY
#include <unwind/libunwind.h>
```

I found it also helped to add "--disable-block-signals" to the configure command - without it, libunwind can end up spending quite a lot of time blocking and unblocking signals around portions of the code. On ARM (where I was testing) this was quite significant.

Even after this, I think there are still some improvements that could be made to libunwind's performance. I was using perf to try to dig in a bit more to this.